# How do I get magnet links to work with Deluge?

Tags: macos, torrent

How do you associate magnet links with [Deluge BitTorrent Client](http://deluge-torrent.org/) on OS X? On other systems, you can associate magnet links with the client through *Preferences*, but this does not seem to be the case with OS X.

Comment: objc[3651]: Objective-C garbage collection is no longer supported I am getting this message when trying to use deluge magnet handler any thoughts

Comment: @kenneth A [GitHub issue about this problem](https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/Deluge-Magnet-Handler/issues/2) has been filed. On the page, you'll find a workaround (that I haven't tried personally), that'll hopefully work until the author of DMH solves the underlying problem (which he says he's trying to).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

On OS X, Deluge is unable to associate itself with magnet links due to GTK-OSX not supporting the feature ([See ticket #2420](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/ticket/2420)).

A workaround is to use [Deluge Magnet Handler](https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/Deluge-Magnet-Handler). To use it, [download the ZIP](https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/Deluge-Magnet-Handler/releases/latest), extract it, move `Magnet Handler.app` to the Applications folder and run it once.

The application works by associating itself with magnet links and adding them to Deluge using a AppleScript when magnet links are pressed.

Answer (score 9):

Right-click Copy Magnet URL

Go to Deluge -> Add -> URL -> Paste -> Go

Answer (score 1):

Grab the link from the browser, throw it on deluge. Simple. Would be great to just click...yes. Prefer not to install another app to get that...yes.